# How to clear (not delete) the last duplicate cell (not row) for the duplicate values found?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I have a sorted column:

```
**NAMES**
Amit
Amit
Amit
Jack
Jack
Jack
Jack
```

I want to clear (not delete) the last duplicate cell (not row) for the duplicate values found.

In above example third Amit and fourth Jack will be cleared from the cell.

I found many macros/VBA that clear duplicates, but none clear only last duplicate values.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  If you paste it into the question, and tell us which bit isn't working as you expect, we can assist you to fix whatever issues you are having.

Comment: Without an attempt being provided, and without one being made and edited in despite being asked, this question can be closed as Too Broad.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that would help:

```
For Each cell In Application.Intersect(InsertNameOfTableHere.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0), InsertNameOfTableHere.Columns(1))
    If cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0) And cell <> cell.Offset(1, 0) Then
        cell.Value = ""
    End If
Next
```